# Creating a generator function for a large data set for a neural network

Tags: neural-networks

After reading documentation on Training on Large Data Sets, I am still at a loss on how to create a generator function, to read a batch of 1000 of this

```
{1, 17, 39, 53, 44, 23} -> {18, 53, 50, 38, 6, 31}
```

For an entire 66GB file. I have tried

```
ReadList[$fileStream, Expression,1000]
```

but this only reads the first 1000.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Also, any good books on this subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = OpenWrite["data.txt"];

SeedRandom[0];
Do[Write[f, RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 5] -> RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 5]], {10000}]

Close[f];
```

```
f = OpenRead["data.txt"];

generator = Function[
   Table[
      With[
       {r = Read[f, Record]},
       If[r === EndOfFile,
        SetStreamPosition[f, 0]; Read[f, Record],
        r
        ]
       ],
      {#BatchSize}
      ] // ToExpression // <|"Input" -> #[[;; , 1]], "Output" -> #[[;; , 2]]|> &
   ];

net = NetChain[
  {
   LinearLayer[16],
   LinearLayer[5]
   },
  "Input" -> 5,
  "Output" -> 5
  ]

SetStreamPosition[f, 0];
netT = NetTrain[
  net,
  {generator, "RoundLength" -> 10},
  All,
  BatchSize -> 1000, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Note: Mathematica seems to ignore `RoundLength` for my generator. Play with `MaxTrainingRounds`.

Comment: Hello, I tried your above code. This also only runs through 1000 entries , the batch does not progress through the whole file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichelMesedahl How did you measure? My generator works cyclically. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvVas0AkeAWi0RHJDhoL5DFtsl6l (`Print@StreamPosition[f]` inserted in generator). For your 66 GB file, you must change `MaxTrainingRounds` (to millions or billions).

Comment: Ok, now I get the jist of it. Thank You